# Why is this 'href' value not working in Opera?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opera

I have the following:

```
<a href="javascript:jQuery('body').css('backgroundColor','red');">Test</a>
```

When run in Chrome, it functions as expected and turns the page red. However, in Opera I get:

> [object Object]

Closer inspection reveals that Opera thinks that `javascript:Query('body')...` is some kind of URL. What am I doing wrong? Doesn't Opera recognize `javascript:` links in the `href` attribute?

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9CZZL/

---

**Edit:** seems to be a Firefox problem too...

Comment: avoid doing this way , handle all click events seperately..this is very old way of doing it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the return value of `jQuery('body').css('backgroundColor','red')` is an object, which some browsers interpret as the new content for the web page. To fix this, you can use the JavaScript [`void`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/void) operator to turn it into `undefined`, which FF and Opera (and potentially others) will handle as you intended. You will notice that this issue is also described on that page, since it's the premier use-case of the `void` operator (other than code golf where `void 0` is less characters than `undefined`).

```
<a href="javascript:void(jQuery('body').css('backgroundColor','red'));">Test</a>
```

This should give the intended result: http://jsfiddle.net/9CZZL/13/

It should be noted that handling clicks this way is considered bad practice. Instead, using event handlers in JavaScript is recommended. This helps separate the different layers of your web app, which in turn will make debugging in the future easier.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a google search and no, apparently Opera does not recognise "javascript:" href values. You would have to implement an onClick or similar solution.

Answer (score 1):

Does it in Firefox too.... not quite sure why. But I never liked putting JavaScript right in the URL... you could try putting it in the `onclick` event or pull the whole thing out and separate it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbayazit/6d5An/

Answer (score 1):

These all work as href values for me in Opera 10.1:

```
javascript:void(0)
javascript:alert("Hello")
javascript:window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'
```

Your snippet does not though.

A viable work around is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="$('body').css('background-color','red')">Test</a>
```

Or even:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="$('body').css('background-color','red')">Test</a>
```

...since that seems to work.

Comment: Ya, I'll probably go with the latter.